# UWP/Appx Manifest Properties For Creating a Desktop Icon on "Installation"

Tags: uwp, installation, desktop, shortcut, appxmanifest

We have moved our application over using the DesktopBridge tool, however we cannot seem to figure out to create a desktop icon/shortcut on the installation sequence.  Is this at all possible? or is it a restriction placed on the Appx store apps not to do so?

Our only solution would be to create this on first launch (at the user's confirmation request) but would prefer to do this via the manifest so that it auto-cleans the shortcut up when the app is uninstalled.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you mean that you want  to create icons on the desktop after the installation is complete? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, we want to create a launchable desktop shortcut/icon for the user to click on that will take them to the application that was installed.